# Apollo client not working on mobile browser

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo

Using Apollo in react that's working on computer but it's not working on mobile browser, I have seen many solutions on here and github but they are all for version 2 or less, I'm using `"@apollo/client": "^3.5.8"` and here's where the occurs

```
        const getSignedUrl = async (file) => {
            
            try {
                const api = await mutationFunc({ variables: { 
                    fileName: file[0].name, 
                    email: currentUser.email 
                }})

                .....

            } catch (error) {
                throw new Error('Unknown error')
            }
        }
```

It does not even connect to the server, I just get `Failed to fetch` error.

According to the deprecated solutions, it has something to do with ApolloClient constructor, so here's my index file:

```
  import React from "react";
  import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
  import App from "./App";
  import {
    ApolloClient,
    InMemoryCache,
    ApolloProvider,
    HttpLink,
    createNetworkInterface
  } from "@apollo/client";


  // const client = new ApolloClient({
  //   link: new HttpLink({
  //   uri: Platform.select({
  //   ios: 'http://localhost:80/',
  //   android: 'http://10.0.2.2:80/',
  //   }),
  //   }),
  //   cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  //   });

  // const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface('/graphql') 
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    // uri: 'http://localhost:8000/',
    link: new HttpLink({ uri: 'http://localhost:8000/' }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  });



  ReactDOM.render(
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <App />,
    </ApolloProvider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
```

**EDIT**

The API lives on my PC, so I tried changing the ApolloClient constructor uri to

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: new HttpLink({ uri: http://192.168.1.101:8000' }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
  });
```

I can also query the API directly on my phone using http://192.168.1.101:8000: Here is the query:

[image]

Here is the response from the API
[image]

and Here is the failed mutation on React side:
[image]

**NOTE:** I'm not uploading the image just send the name to get a pre-signed s3 url. But it's not even sending to the api.

Answer (score 0):

Where does your GraphQL server run? I assume it doesn't run on the mobile device. If so, you have to specify the URL of the server in Apollo client constructor.

http://localhost:8000/ --> http://myserver:8000/

And of course your mobile device should have access to port 8000 of myserver.

Comment: I put in few edits for you

Comment: So I just deployed the API and now it's working, turns out localhost to localhost don't work on mobile. You can edit the answer and I'll accept just for others to learn from my misery.

Comment: Hi! localhost works on both mobile and PC but they are different machines. The graphql runs on your PC, the web browser runs on your mobile. That's why you cannot access the graphql server on your mobile using localhost.

Comment: Right! Do you want to add that to your answer?